# R reformatting data to create a parallel coordinates plot

Tags: r

I'm a total R novice in need of some help. I'm trying to reformat data which currently look like this:

| ID | AgeT1 | AgeT2 | ScoreT1 | ScoreT2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 7 | 15 | 22 |
| 2 | 12 | 13 | 5 | 10 |
| 3 | 10 | 12 | 6 | 6 |

etc.

To look like this:

1st row: age in years / 1st column: ID / Values: Score

| ID | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 |  | 22 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 5 | 10 |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 6 |  | 6 |  |

I'm trying create a parrallel coordinates plot in order to visualise score changes over time.
Thanks for your help!
J

Comment: I would recommend against the structure you show. A lot of R works really well with "tidy" data sets, structured with each row is an observation including all the data for that observation. So, three columns - ID, age, and score.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above the data structure you are asking for would be hard to plot, and tidy data would make your life easier.  Can pivot longer the data set then plot.

```
library(tidyverse)

DATA_LONG <- DATA %>% pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = c(".value", "Sample"), names_sep = "T")

DATA_LONG %>% ggplot(aes(Age, Score, colour=factor(ID)))+geom_path()
```

Comment: 's solution needs you to first have installed and load libraries `ggplot2` and `tidyr`. Not sure if that will give you the pipe `%>%` -- you can use base R `|>` instead